# Nestable is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse erro de TypeError: $(...).nestable is not a function, eu estou tentando colocar uma lista pro usuário poder mexer nos itens mas o nestable não quer funcionar, abaixo meu código até agr.

```
<script src="js/plugins/nestable/jquery.nestable.js"></script>

          <div class="dd">
            <ol class="dd-list">
              <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
                <div class="dd-handle">Item 1</div>
              </li>
              <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">
                <div class="dd-handle">Item 2</div>
              </li>
              <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">
                <div class="dd-handle">Item 3</div>
              </li>
              <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">
                <div class="dd-handle">Item 4</div>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </div>



$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.dd').nestable({
    group: 1
  });
});
```

Comment: tem o script do nestable carregado na página?

Comment: Tem sim tinha esquecido de colocar na pergunta rs, editei e coloquei ali

Comment: não há logs de erros no console do navegador? pode ser que algo não tenha carregado algum script ou erro no javascript da pagina

Comment: O único erro q esta aparecendo no log é esse do nestable is not a function mesmo.

Comment: Incluiu o Jquery antes do nestable ?